# LINQ Project properties into a new anonymous type with Contains

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

I have the following code which I am trying to make work but it still does not compile.  Thank you.

```
List<Employee> emploees = new List<Employee>() 
{ 
    new Employee { ID = 101, Name = "Rosy" },
    new Employee { ID = 102, Name = "Sury" }
};

var result = emploees.Select(x=> new {x.ID, x.Name}).Contains(new Employee { ID = 101, Name = "Rosy" });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I am just wondering, why u need to create anonymous type, if you just need to check whether employee exist in array or not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to project your list items to anonymous object. 
Also, IMO `Any()` is much more appropriate for this situation rather than `Contains()`:

```
var result = emploees.Any(x => x.ID == 101 && x.Name == "Rosy");
```

If you still want to use `Contains`, then you need to create ***comparer*** for `Employee` class.

```
sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;
        else if (y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return x.ID == y.ID && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
         unchecked
         {
              int hash = 17;
              hash = hash * 23 + obj.ID.GetHashCode();
              hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
              return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

And change your code as:

```
  var result = emploees.Contains(new Employee { ID = 101, Name = "Rosy" }, new MyComparer());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But what if I want keep contains?

Comment: @NicolaSmith Then you need to create your comparer,

Comment: @NicolaSmith Glad to help, I have updtaed my answer as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you projecting into an anonymous type then doing a type comparison check?

You can simply use `Any` to achieve what you need here:

```
var result = emploees
   .Select(x=> new {x.ID, x.Name})
   .Any(x => x.ID == 101 && x.Name == "Rosy");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Or simply, without the `Select` as you're just using the `bool`:

```
bool result = emploees
   .Any(x => x.ID == 101 && x.Name == "Rosy");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For completeness sake though, if you **really** wanted to use `Contains`, override the `IEquatable` for your `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee : IEquatable<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals( Employee other)
    {
        return this.ID == other.ID && 
           this.Name == other.Name;
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
var result = emploees
    .Select(x => new Employee {x.ID, x.Name})
    .Contains(new Employee { ID = 101, Name = "Rosy" });

    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: With the 3rd approach, you must check for `Contains` with the same reference to the `Employee` which is in the collection, or have the `Employee` class override the equality comparison to compare the given fields.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yep, you're right. For what it's worth the `Contains` is too much extra work so I've removed that example, it's pointless having to override the equality comparer when `Any` can do the job perfectly fine here.

Comment: Thank yuo mattytommo.

Comment: @NIcolaSmith No problems, I've actually added a variant to use `Contains` just for reference really.